# Layout issues after upgrading WKHTMLTOPDF

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf, wkhtmltopdf-binary

All my layouts that looked great before are now messed up, appears to be rendering with a different and smaller font after upgrading `WKHTMLTOPDF`. Full-width divs are also rendering smaller than before.

I've tried modifying the dpi flag in wicked, I saw a small difference, when set to `dpi: 300`, but the difference didn't seem to remedy the issue, no matter the change to `dpi`. Anyone have any hints? Pretty sure the issue is with changes made to `WKHTMLTOPDF`.

We had these versions locked in for a while, as the rendered PDFs looked great:

- `wicked_pdf (1.1.0)`
- `wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.9.9.3)` (Rendered using the font NimbusSansL Bold & Regular)

We have a new feature that requires better handling of page-breaks in long tables. Page-breaks are working great now that we've upgraded, but now we have more issues, here are the new versions:

- `wicked_pdf (1.2.2)`
- `wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.12.4)` (Now rendering with the font, DejaVuSans, Bold & Regular)

Code for rendering:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: 'report',
             template: 'download_report.pdf.erb',
             show_as_html: params[:debug].present?,
             layout: 'report_application.pdf',
             margin: {
                 top: 5,
                 bottom: 5,
                 left: 5,
                 right: 5
             }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `zoom` option seemed to fix the majority of my layout issues. The affected divs have and require pixel width defined. I determined the amount of zoom by resizing one of the divs back to its previous, rendered, size. Divide the new width by the old width to get your zoom:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: 'report',
             zoom: 1.27,
             template: 'download_report.pdf.erb',
             show_as_html: params[:debug].present?,
             layout: 'report_application.pdf',
             margin: {
                 top: 5,
                 bottom: 5,
                 left: 5,
                 right: 5
             }
    end
  end
```